# Practical concerns for changing text on the "add to cart" in Drupal Commerce to use it as a "wishlist"

Tags: commerce

Apologize for the roundabout question, just not sure how to get at this more directly. I'm developing a commerce site where our clients will be submitting inquiry lists that we will respond to, rather than orders. In essence, what I need is the shopping cart, minus the payment gateway (which is where the site is headed). As a quick fix, I was thinking of just changing the text on the "add to cart" and "check out" buttons, as the basic functionality we need is there out of the box without a payment gateway. Is there a glaringly obvious reason not to do this? I am developing a parallel wishlist application with flags, but I haven't hacked the functionality I need into that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, upon conducting a lot of research, modifying the existing architecture in DC is possible, but appears to be non-trivial to apply. The checkout process has many hard coded titles and elements that, while instructive to research and attempt to modify lead me to believe that this implementation as a work-around is probably more effort than just throwing together a custom module for the functionality I'm looking for. If anyone reads this from the Drupal Commerce team: the internet is LOADED with requests on how to modify this stuff through the admin functions of DC, great work and much appreciated, but this noobs head hurts.

```
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
dpm($form_id);
dpm($form);
if (commerce_form_callback($form_id, $form_state) == "commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form"){
    $form['submit']['#attributes']['title'] = $form['submit']['#attributes']['value']=t("Add to Inquiry List");
    }
if(strpos($form_id, 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default')===0){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t("Update List");
    $form['actions']['checkout']['#value'] = t("Submit List");
}
if(strpos($form_id, 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout')===0){
    $form['buttons']['continue']['#value'] = t('Proceed to final list submission.');
    }
if(strpos($form_id, 'commerce_checkout_form_review')===0){
    $form['buttons']['continue']['#value'] = t('Submit your inquiry list');
    }
```

}